# Google API Consistently locks out with redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: php, api, youtube

I'm trying to connect to the YouTube API to collect the transcripts of my videos, but when I attempt to connect via OAuth the Auth URL generated by the PHP Google API always results in a 400 error:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.
> If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.

Before you say anything I've already authorized the url on the development console. Not only that, I went hog wild and authorized every different variation of the url (adding a variant with /index.php, and doing both http and https variants). I specifically copied and pasted the URL in the "Request details" section of that page and authorized that url. But nothing I'm doing works. Even more than 5 minutes later I'm still getting the redirect_uri_mismatch.

Googling the issue only brings up people consistently missing the part in the developer console, but I have definitely done that part. I can even get it to work in other contexts, just not this particular page, and at this point I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the domain name to an ip address (or in my case "localhost" to "127.0.0.1")

Comment: Please remember [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - Thank you.